# How to make a join in order to get this result

Tags: sql, join

I have problem joining two tables to get result as in Table_C.

- Option A gives access to all rooms A
- Option B gives access to all rooms of A option and B option
- Option B gives access to all rooms of A option and B option and C option

How do I join these tables table_A and table_B to get something like table_C

table_A

```
name    option  sex
Ann     A       K
Cezar   B       M
Martha  C       K
```

table_B

```
Room        option
pool        A
river       A
gym         B
slide       B
spa         C
sauna       C
```

table_C

```
name    option  sex Room
Ann     A       F   Pool
Ann     A       F   River
Cezar   B       M   Pool
Cezar   B       M   River
Cezar   B       M   Gym
Cezar   B       M   Slide
Martha  C       F   Pool
Martha  C       F   River
Martha  C       F   Gym
Martha  C       F   Slide
Martha  C       F   Spa
Martha  C       F   Sauna
```

Comment: (1) I assume that you mean that C gives access to A, B, and C.  (2) You should tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inequalities in `JOIN`s.  That seems to be what you want:

```
select a.*, b.*
from table_A a join
     table_B b
     on b.option <= a.option
```

Answer (score 0):

> what output you want here is your query :)

```
create table table_A (name varchar(10),[option] varchar(1),sex varchar(1))
create table table_B(Room varchar(10),[option] varchar(1))

insert into table_A VAlues ('Ann', 'A','K')
insert into table_A VAlues ('Cezar','B', 'M')
insert into table_A VAlues ('Martha' ,'C'  ,'K')

insert into table_B values('pool '       ,'A')
insert into table_B values('river'       ,'A')
insert into table_B values('gym  '       ,'B')
insert into table_B values('slide'       ,'B')
insert into table_B values('spa  '       ,'C')
insert into table_B values('sauna'       ,'C')



select a.[name],a.[option],a.sex,b.Room from table_A A
INNER join table_B b on a.[option] >= b.[option]
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's solution will work fine for that sample data.
Since A < B < C

But if it needs to more explicit:

```
select a.name, b.[option], a.sex, b.Room
from table_A a 
join table_B b
     on b.[option] = a.[option] -- include same option
     or b.[option] = 'A'  -- always include option A rooms
     or (b.[option] = 'B' and a.[option] = 'C')
```